# SQL Server Date Formats -- ddd

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, date

How do I get the day of the week (in ddd format, so Mon, Tue etc.) in SQL ?
I don't see anything about it in the CAST and CONVERT documentation..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many ways to do it, here's one way:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()), 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) method to extract the day and then use the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to only take the first 3 chars.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW, '09/11/2009'), 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use
`SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(weekday,GETDATE()))`
so as to avoid using another function in the SQL, the conversion to a CHAR(3) implicitly takes the first 3 characters.

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW, '1/1/2009')
```

Read up DATEPART here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't ddd out of the box but you can do the full day

e.g.

`select datename(weekday,getdate())`

returns 'Monday' and you can just take the first 3 letters.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(),'ddd') AS ShortDayName
```

This is much cleaner than a substring solution. The `FORMAT()` function can also be passed a culture for locale-aware formatting.

Note that this works for other date parts, such as month:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETUTCDATE(),'MMM') AS ShortMonthName
```

[FORMAT() Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out when I'm finally on SQL 2012! Perhaps before 2020